# Disable scrolling behaviour in Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, mouse, taskbar, scrolling

Sometimes my mouse accidentally moves too low, and gets over the taskbar while I am trying to scroll, which results in the active window being replaced by the next one, i.e. the next window pops up and covers my focal one.

Note, that I'm not talking about scrolling among icons in a crowded taskbar that only show a fraction of windows (as can be seen [in this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Windows_XP_task_grouping_(Luna).png)), neither about [this issue](https://superuser.com/q/337883/113517), but about the fact that when I move my mouse wheel while being over the taskbar the next window will pop up *without* me clicking on its taskbar icon.

**Is it possible to disable scrolling behaviour in the Windows 7 taskbar?**

Comment: @ejbytes I entirely not see the relevance of my mouse hardware to this issue. Is this some kind of advertisement? In my case, there is a single middle wheel that I use all the time as one would expect. I just don't want the scroll functionality in the Windows taskbar. I don't think it matters what mouse I use.

Comment: @ejbytes My mouse works perfectly fine and assuming that I don't know how to use it is bordering an offense. Do you have Win7? Do you have a taskbar with multiple windows minimized on it? Do you have any taskbar tweaker application? Have you tried scrolling your mouse while hovering over the taskbar? What settings do you use for your windows taskbar? Why on Earth would anyone close the question?? The answer is not accepted, and even if I would accept one, that doesn't mean the question should be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to try,

1) Move the taskbar to the top which will fix your problem though it may be a bit odd for someone who is used to it at the bottom. Having used OSX it wasn't hard to get used to it myself and I found that it was easier on the hand that operated the mouse.

2) Try [7+ TaskBar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker). I just started using it myself and has made working with 7's taskbar much better. It does have an option for the wheel. You might have turned it on and forgot about it.

[image]

Comment: You were right in that Taskbar Tweaker does have an option to control the wheel. It's just not among Advanced options, but in the general interface - which I forgot to check now. Anyway, it was turned on, and I forgot about it years ago, until it started to annoy me now.

Comment: @IstvánZachar So, it was your mouse after all! How did I know that. And the virus, I mean tweakware, was installed by you.

Comment: @ejbytes I really hope that you're joking. For what it matters, you could have simply told me that "something is wrong with my computer" to put me on the right track, you vates : )

Comment: @IstvánZachar LOL! At least your nerves can relax now. Happy Days are here again...